# How to substitute spaces with underscores in all entries in a bash array

Tags: arrays, macos, bash, unix, whitespace

I'm trying to fill an array with the files in a folder, but if there are white spaces in their name, they are splitted and the array filled with single words.
This is the code with which I try to replace blank spaces with underscore:

```
 array=($(ls)) | sed -r 's/ /_/g'
```

How to record the **ls** items into a bash array?

Comment: **Never** try to make programmatic use of `ls` output! http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Basically -- when you do `array=( $(ls) )`, the individual items **don't contain spaces at all**, because any file named `name with a space` has already become four separate array entries: `name`, `with`, `a`, and `space`.

Comment: ...you can work around that with a custom value for IFS, but even that only works with a subset of possible filenames; how any version of `ls` behaves with nonprintable characters is implementation-defined.

Comment: ...if you want something fancy that `ls` can do for human-generated output, such as sorting by mtime, the answer that works correctly across all possible filenames (a set that includes names with newlines) is to use `find` instead to generate a NUL-delimited stream, and to sort that stream with similar NUL-aware tools (GNU sort's `sort -z`, for instance). It's not a lot of fun, but until POSIX adds `ls -0`, it's what we've got -- and there are plenty of on-topic questions and answers describing the process.

Comment: BTW, `IFS=$'\n'; array=( $(ls | sed -r 's/ /_/g') )` would be closer to what you were initially trying to write, but still incorrect -- prone to undesired glob expansion, unable to represent filenames containing literal newlines, and potentially incorrect with other nonprintable characters depending on your implementation of `ls`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array=( * )                  # populate array with filenames
array=( "${array[@]// /_}" ) # convert spaces to underscores in all array elements
```

To explain:

- `array=( $(ls) )` can't be safely used: Unescaped expansion expands globs (if you had a file named `*`, it would be replaced with a list of other names) and splits on all whitespace by default (meaning that a file named `two words` would become two array entries, the first being `two` and the second being `words`). Moreover, the behavior of `ls` with nonprintable characters is undefined, and its output with files containing literal newlines is necessarily ambiguous.
- `"${foo// /_}"` is an expansion of shell variable `foo`, with all spaces replaced with underscores. (`${foo/ /_}` would replace only the first space with an underscore). For an array, the usual syntax change is applied: `${foo[@]// /_}`. This syntax is comprehensively described in [BashFAQ #100 (How do I do string manipulations in bash?)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).